# How to perform status validation for lots of Linq to Sql Objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to perform status validation for maybe hundreds or thousands of linq to sql objects.
For example, only `Status A` & `B` can change to `Status C`, then `C` can change to `D`, ...

Considering performance and scalability, what is the best solution?
Will "DetectChanges" suitable for my scenario?

Comment: this doesn't seem like nearly enough information for anyone to give you an answer.  also, asking for 'best solution' is generally frowned upon here as it seems higly subjective.

Comment: what you need is a state machine implementation. That will handle status change of given Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a simple implementation of **state machine concept** in your code.

As it is fairly known concept in software engineering, i will just provide usefull resources with examples to follow and implement this concept.

Here you are the resources:

- [Basic State Machine setup using Stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9117487/1437962)
- [A Simple State Machine using a Static class in C# to notify other subscribers via Events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2411803/1437962)

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's a well known concept and I'll try to see its performance when calling in a loop.